# Nodemailer attachments are empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I'm trying to attach some files to the email I'm sending via NodeMailer. Checking the sent email, the attached files are empty (i.e. 0 bytes). If I download the attachments, I end up with empty text files. What am I missing?

**Here is my code:**

```js
 const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

 const lessSecureAuth = {
  user: "sender@email.com",
  pass: "password123"
 }
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: lessSecureAuth
 });

 const mailOptions = {
      from: 'sender@email.com',
      to: 'recipient@email.com',
      subject: 'Email Subject',
      html: `
          <h3>Hello World!</h3>
          <p>
              the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
          </p>
      `,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: 'attachFileTest.docx',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachFileTest.docx',
          contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        },
        {
          filename: 'attachFileTest.pdf',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachFileTest.pdf',
          contentType: 'application/pdf'
        },
        {
          filename: 'attachImageTest.png',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachImageTest.png',
          contentType: 'image/png'
        }
      ]
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log("[ ERR ]", error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
```

**NodeJS**: v12.16.1

**nodemailer**: v6.6.0

**Edit#1**

As suggested by @Apoorva Chikara
[image]

Comment: Does it send the body and other details? Can you check the path of file is correct and files are present there?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Yep, it sends the email body & subject and the files are present in the uploads folder.

Comment: I would suggest you to add debug mode and logger in the options. check [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#debug-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging in the docs and other stackoverflow posts, I found the answer:

Using the **absolute path** instead of a **relative path** to the file to be attached, along with using the `attachment.path` property instead of the `attachment.filePath` property did the trick.

*Basically, changing this:*

```js
 {
   filename: 'attachFileTest.pdf',
   filePath: '../uploads/attachFileTest.pdf',
   contentType: 'application/pdf'
 },
```

*to this:*

```js
 {
  path: __dirname + '/../uploads/attachFileTest.pdf' // string concatination
  // path: `${__dirname}/../uploads/attachFileTest.pdf` // or string interpolation (ES6)
 }
```

Both `attachment.filename` and `attachment.contentType` are unnecessary in this case, since according to the [docs](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/):

> ```
> { // filename and content type is derived from path
>   path: '/path/to/file.txt'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the Header - Content-Type that is why it is causing an issue. You could also try a sample attachment like this and check if it works :

```
attachments: [
        {
          filename: 'attachFileTest.docx',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachFileTest.docx',
          //contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        },
        {
          filename: 'attachFileTest.pdf',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachFileTest.pdf',
          //contentType: 'application/pdf'
        },
        {
          filename: 'attachImageTest.png',
          filePath: '../uploads/attachImageTest.png',
         // contentType: 'image/png'
        },
        {   // utf-8 string as an attachment. add this and check
            filename: 'text1.txt',
            content: 'hello world!'
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Removing the `contentType` property yields the same result: empty attachments. Adding the text file attachment results in only the text file being attached.

Comment: @kbien the reason for attaching a text file is to find out the issue with path if you can see the data in it, your files are not attached properly. And moatly this is due to path.